# Show Update of a Global Variable on a HTML Page with Angular 13

Tags: angular

I want to create global functions and global variables that should be called from several components. When I change the value of a global variable from a function located in a service, it does not work. I can't display the content update of the global variable `{{ gCourseTitle }}` on the HTML page. What do I need to make it work?

The value of the variable `{{ gCourseTitle }}` changes in the console, but not on the HTML page.

Here is the test I performed:
[Show Update of a Global Variable on a HTML Page](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m42s39)

### global-component.ts

Definition of the global variable gCourseTitle.

```js
export class GlobalComponent {
  public static gCourseTitle: string = '';
}
```

### functions.service.ts

```js
import { GlobalComponent } from './global-component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FunctionsService {
  gCourseTitle = GlobalComponent.gCourseTitle;

  constructor() {}

  displayCourseTitle03(courseTitle: string) {
    this.gCourseTitle = courseTitle;
    console.log(this.gCourseTitle);
  }
}
```

### app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { GlobalComponent } from './global-component';
import { FunctionsService } from './functions.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  gCourseTitle = GlobalComponent.gCourseTitle;

  constructor(private functionsService: FunctionsService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.gCourseTitle = 'Course Title';
  }

  // Function located in the component.
  public displayCourseTitle01(courseTitle: string) {
    this.gCourseTitle = courseTitle;
    console.log(this.gCourseTitle);
  }
  // Function located in a service.
  public displayCourseTitle02(courseTitle: string) {
    this.functionsService.displayCourseTitle03(courseTitle);
  }
}
```

### app.component.html

The value of the variable `{{ gCourseTitle }}` changes in the console but not on the HTML page.

```js
<h1>Show Update of a Global Variable on a HTML Page</h1>
<h2>{{ gCourseTitle }}</h2>

<p>
  Function located in the component<br />
  The update of the variable <b>gCourseTitle</b> works on the HTML page.
</p>
<div>
  <button (click)="displayCourseTitle01('Course 1 (component)')">
    Course 1 (component)
  </button>
  <button (click)="displayCourseTitle01('Course 2 (component)')">
    Course 2 (component)
  </button>
</div>

<p>
  Function located in a service.<br />
  The update of the variable <b>gCourseTitle</b> does not work on the HTML page (but it works from the console).
</p>
<div>
  <button (click)="displayCourseTitle02('Course 1 (service)')">
    Course 1 (service)
  </button>
  <button (click)="displayCourseTitle02('Course 2 (service)')">
    Course 2 (service)
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Services are `Singleton` classes. So there is no need for static or global variables. Just declare any variables that you want shared within a service.

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TestService {
  gCourseTitle = '';
}
```

**Set the variable in One Component**

```js
export class OneComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private ts: TestService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ts.gCourseTitle = 'Title Changed In One Component';
  }
}
```

**Read from Two Component**

```js
export class TwoComponent {
  constructor(public ts: TestService) {}
}
```

```html
<p>{{ ts.gCourseTitle }}</p>
```

Two component shows `"Title Changed In One Component"`

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations. It's fantastic. Your help allowed me to move forward more easily in my experimentation.

Here is a new test I performed:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cb5rug